# error in google chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome, mootools

I am listing files from a directory and for each one there is a delete link, in firefox all works but with chrome when I want to display the list, I get this error, I dont know how to fix it

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 4 at column 44: Opening and ending tag mismatch: root line 0 and br
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $$('a.delete').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e.stop();
        var id = this.get('id');
        var DeleteFile = new Request({
//            method: 'POST',
//            data: 'archivo='+id,
            url: 'deletefile.php?archivo='+id,
            onRequest: function() {},
            onSuccess: function(text, xmlanswer) {
                //alert(text);
            $('page_container').load('script2.php');
            },
            onFailure: function(){alert('Error!');}
    }).send();
//        DeleteFile.send({ data: { 'archivo': id } });
    });
});
</script>


<?php

$ruta = "./uploadedfiles/";
$directorio = dir($ruta);
$types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xlsx', 'pptx');
$identificador = "";


while ($archivo = $directorio->read()) {
    $division = explode(".", $archivo);
    $extension = end($division);
    $identificador = $archivo;


   if(in_array($extension, $types)){

      echo $archivo . "<a id=\"". urlencode($identificador)."\" href=\"#\" class=\"delete\">Delete</a></br>";


//echo $archivo . "&nbsp;<a id=\"". $identificador."\" href=deletefile.php?archivo=" . urlencode($archivo) .">Delete</a><br>";
      //echo $archivo. "<a id=refresh href=# >Delete</a><br> ";

   }

}

$directorio->close();
?>
```

Comment: We don't know what the actual HTML looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<br>` and `</br>` tags are both wrong and mismatched.

The `<br />` tag cannot have content; you should always make it a self-closing tag (`<br />`)

Comment: you are right I get it work with your help, but now my problem is in Internet explorer